# Is there a way to check if a phpspec array has a key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, phpspec

Given a multidimensional array, I try to run        somearray->shouldHaveKey('somekey') but it only searches at the first dimension and not down through the multidimensional array

Answer (score 1):

I think you must create an [inline matcher](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/cookbook/matchers.html#inline-matcher) as described in PHPSpec guide

Answer (score 0):

In php you can just insert the array with the specific path to an isset check:

```
isset($a['some']['not']['existing']);
```

I don't know [phpspec](/questions/tagged/phpspec), but i think there must be something like `isTrue()`, so you could check the Response of isset.